# .tgz.md5 and .tgz.sha1 download skipping JFrog Artifactory using pipeline script

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, artifactory, jfrog-cli, artifactory-query-lang

Here is the snippet of code where **I am trying to download some folder contents from jfrog to in jenkins pipeline script**

```
    stage ('Pull from BAMS Artifactory')
    {
        def server = Artifactory.newServer url: u_rl, credentialsId: creds

            def downloadSpec = """{
                                     "files": [
                                      {
                                          "pattern": "default.npm.global/transfer-pricing/ooxp-common-lib/*.**",
                                          "target": "default.npm.global/"
                                        }
                                     ]
                                  }"""
            server.download(downloadSpec)
    }

    The fallowing are the files in that folder ooxp-common-lib
    ../
    ooxp-common-lib-1.0.0.tgz        30-Oct-2018 22:33  14.24 KB
    ooxp-common-lib-1.0.0.tgz.md5    30-Oct-2018 22:33  32 bytes
    ooxp-common-lib-1.0.0.tgz.sha1   30-Oct-2018 22:33  40 bytes
```

**How ever .tgz file is downloading and the files .tgz.md5 and .tgz.sh1 are not dowloading to workspace**
,
I Tried many ways but could not able to download those extensions files.
Can someone please help me quickly please.

Comment: Did you try this pattern?: "default.npm.global/transfer-pricing/ooxp-common-lib/*"

Answer (score 1):

The query you are using is a part of [Artifactory Query Language](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Query+Language), in which `*` replaces any string, and `?` replaces any character, until it hits the next dot in the query. That's why `*.**` will catch `ooxp-common-lib-1.0.0.tgz`, but won't catch `ooxp-common-lib-1.0.0.tgz`.

The solution, as @yahavi suggested in the comments is just using one `*` which will catch everything: `default.npm.global/transfer-pricing/ooxp-common-lib/*`